# GET console error on all pages

Tags: linux, ssh

Image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/haLyF.jpg

I'm getting this error on all my pages and I'm not sure what it could be. I took out some code bit by bit to see if there is something in the code stopping it but nothing worked so I'm thinking its a server issue. Now, yesterday I had to downgrade php to 5.3.2 to get a package installed (php5-sybase) and this caused arrays such as $array = []; to not work so then I upgraded it today to 5.4.2 and everything was working fine except for this console error.

Does anyone have a clue what the problem could be? Am I missing something server-side?

Also, none of my JS and jQuery is working anymore.

I looked at the Apache error log but I'm not experienced enough to see something wrong. Most of whats in there from today are regular PHP errors when I was attempting a connecting to a MS SQL server.

Comment: What you show in your print-screen does not help a lot...Seems you have an error at line 1 in file `email_list.php`, that's all...Providing Apache error log or `email_list.php` code could help

Comment: I don't have an error on line 1. On firefox the page is taking 15 seconds to load completely (php, and js) Does this help? I'm really leaning towards an issue with the server but I don't know how to help you so you can help me @user2196728

Answer (score 0):

If this is your own local machine:

1. open your terminal
2. do `sudo vim /etc/php.ini` (vim is irrevelant, sudo permissions are what is important).
3. search for the line "display_errors"
4. make sure the line says "display_errors = On"
5. search for the line "display_startup_errors"
6. make sure the line says "display_startup_errors = On"
7. save the file and exit your text editor
8. restart apache
9. refresh your page to see the error message from PHP on the page

If this is not your local machine, but it's okay to publicly display the error messages:

1. Open your php script in a text editor
2. Add `<?php ini_set("display_errors", "On"); ini_set("display_startup_errors", "On"); ?>` at the top of your page
3. Save and upload that file to the server
4. Refresh in your browser to see the error

If the file is remote and you don't want to show error messages to public:

1. ssh into your remote server
2. type `$ php -i | grep "error_log"` and press enter. (This essentially searches or `grep`s through the output of your phpinfo() function for a line that has the error_log directive in it).
3. The output should be something like "error_log => /tmp/php_errors.log => /tmp/php_errors.log"
4. Empty that file (ex: /tmp/php_errors.log) but don't delete it
5. Add this command to the top of your php script `<?php ini_set("log_errors", "On"); error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); ?>` (This makes sure that errors are logged to the file we found earlier).
6. Refresh the page in the browser to trigger the error
7. Look at the log file (ex: /tmp/php_errors.log) to find your errors.

I'm not sure what to tell you about the jQuery plugins not working. I'd start by looking for 404 errors in your Chrome console, then carefully examine the paths. Confirm that the files are still on the server where you think they should be. Is php adding the javascript dynamically to the page, or are the paths hardcoded in? Tell me more and I'll provide a better answer on the second part of your question :-)

Comment: I did php -i | grep "error_log" on the server through ssh and I got error_log => no value => no value

Comment: On firefox everything loads but after 15 seconds.